# Working with an existing TypeScript typing file with a catch-all type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am working with an existing TypeScript typing file with limited experience of creating them. There are types that I understand, e.g.

```
contactId: undefined | string

Populate(id: undefined | string, referenceType: ReferenceType): void
```

However, in many of the typing files there is the following type definition that I don't understand

```
[key: string]: any
```

It seems to be a catch-all type for certain functions - (I was wondering how does it enforce type-safety, or what types are allowable using this?)

So basically, my main question is "What is the classification of this type?"

I can then hopefully locate it in the TypeScript handbook / docs and learn more about it? I was looking here before posting this question: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html

Comment: Please [edit] to ask a single question, or make it clear which of your multiple questions is the primary one.  The answer to the first question "what is the classification of this type" is probably that you're looking at an [index signature](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), and an index signature whose value is of type `any` is quite loose indeed.  I don't think we can answer the last question about *why* you'd want to use it in the hypothetical situation you mention... at least not without more details. But hopefully that's not the primary question.

Answer (score 0):

This is called `Index Signatures`. You can use this when you know the type of the keys and their values.

```
interface Example {
   [key: string]: string;
}
```

It has many use cases :)